# Spyder is unable to show the variable you're trying to view because the module 'Prod' was not fount in your Spyder environment

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using Spyder 4.1.5 with and getting an error when trying to explore a modules' object. The object contain DataFrames.

[image]

Comment: pls add the code you were working on, so we can see the code, and also were you debugging the code or trying to run it?

Comment: @python_user yes, I don't believe the problem is with the code itself, as I am able to extract the object's dataframe by storing each object's dataframe under another name3 outside the l 'object (x = Object.DataFrame). But not able to open the object and see all it's components.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The message says it all: you need to install the `Prod` module in the same environment where Spyder is installed. Otherwise we won't be able to show it through the variable explorer.

Comment: Thank you @CarlosCordoba. Do you know how i can Install a module in the Spyder environment ?

Comment: You need to open a system terminal (the Anaconda Prompt if you're on Windows) and install the `Prod` module there (without knowing more details about that module, I can't give you more details, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by adding the script path to the spyder PYTHONPATH manager.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6gc3.png)